# Cmake:build YASM source files

Tags: c++, cmake, yasm

I am using CMake 3.4.1 to generate and build Visual Studio 2013 64bit C++ solution.One of the project also contains .asm files which we compile in VisualStudio with yasm assembler as lib.How do I configure CMake to use yasm for those files?I haven't found any documentation with example of how to set it up.

Comment: Maybe through [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a the following example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(YasmCmake)

find_program(YASM_EXE NAMES yasm)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT hello.o COMMAND ${YASM_EXE}
                   ARGS -f elf64 -o hello.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hello.asm)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
add_library(Hello hello.o)
set_target_properties(Hello PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Of course you need to specify the flags for yasm depending on your platform.